# How to auto-format in vim quickly

Tags: vim

As a beginner for vim , I met some problem when format my code. Here is a tiny example to explain what I want.The code below is my original file without any formatting.It looks too crowd

```
#include <stdio.h>       
static int global=1;
static void test(int a,int b);            
int main(){   
    int local=1;
    int useless=local+1;
    printf("hello,world\n");
    test(1,2);
}
static void test(int a,int b){
    int c=a*b+a-b;
    return;
    }
```

I want style look like:

```
int useless = local + 1;
```

or

```
test(1 , 2);
```

I try `:!indent --linux-style %` in command mode and gets

```
#include <stdio.h>
static int global = 1;
static void test(int a, int b);
int main()
{
    int local = 1;
    int useless = local + 1;
    printf("hello,world\n");
    test(1, 2);
}
static void test(int a, int b)
{
    int c = a * b + a - b;
    return;
}
```

Though it works, there are two annoying points for me:

1. !indent --linux-style % is too long and less efficent
2. I want to auto format each time I input one single line,such as test(1,2) -> test(1, 2);

So is there other solution ? THX

Comment: What is "too long and less efficent" in `!indent --linux-style %`? Typing the command or the time it takes for it to run? See `:help 'equalprg'` or `:help 'formatprg'` to ease the former.

Comment: @romainl typing comand is too long.  I want it behava like vscode that automatically format line. I will try formatprg. thx

Answer (score 1):

To satisfy your need you could just use [autocmd](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html)

```
au BufWritePre *.cpp,*.c %!indent --linux-style
```

It will run command before each file save

Answer (score 0):

I try this plugin:
https://github.com/vim-autoformat/vim-autoformat

and solved my problem